# ASP.NET Application Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

My company is going to be "breaking ground" on a (large!) ASP.NET application in the near future here. We're currently in the design phase and most of the ASP.NET application's I've developed in the past were relatively small -- less than a few dozen pages and 1 or 2 developers.

Can anyone point out any resources, either online or otherwise, that include some kinds of best practices or common architectures for large ASP.NET applications?

Cheers,
Brad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [patterns & practices guidance for Web applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb969054.aspx#web_apps) is not a bad place to start.  Just don't get too dogmatic about following everything to the letter in those documents.

Answer (score 6):

[The Onion Architecture (sorta like the Hexagonal architecture):](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)

Jeffrey Palermo has done a wonderful job with this architecture. It's a really nice approach to coding in a loosely-coupled way that facilitates Test Driven Development, Domain Driven Design and generally good practices overall. Also, checkout Domain Driven Design book by Eric Evans (Its written with Java examples, but I am using for a C# project no problems.)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Application Architecture Guide](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide) from Patterns & Practices.  It's not all ASP.NET, but it's comprehensive and free and deals with all layers of an architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some help from a similar question: [Architectural question: In what assembly should I put which class, for a clean solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147343/architectural-question-in-what-assembly-should-i-put-which-class-for-a-clean-so).